# Three.js deleting an item - GridHelper

Tags: three.js

I have put some grids into my scene with the gridhelper. However, it doesn't always remove itself from the scene when I delete it.

Here is the code where I go through a delete the grids and the axis. Why doesn't this remove the grids from the scene? Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
    for (var ObjID in this.Scene.__objects)                                                                                                                         
    {   if (this.Scene.__objects[ObjID] instanceof THREE.GridHelper){    this.Scene.remove(this.Scene.__objects[ObjID]); this.Scene.__objects.splice(ObjID,1);  }       
        if (this.Scene.__objects[ObjID] instanceof THREE.AxisHelper){ this.Scene.remove(this.Scene.__objects[ObjID]); this.Scene.__objects.splice(ObjID,1);  }      
    }
```

Comment: Usually it's a bad idea to use properties of an object with a name beginning with an underscore, almost always they are intended to be private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the GridHelper a name when you create it:

```
    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(1000, 5);
    grid.position.set(45,0,25);
    grid.name = "GridHelper";
    scene.add(grid);
```

Then you can call:

```
    scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("Grid"));
```

Or if you change your grid Object Variable to a global variable you can just use:

```
    scene.remove(grid);
```

Your Code is wrong and don't works everytime because the Grid-Center (obj.geometry.BoundingSphere.center.x / y / z) is'nt always in the scene, so the If-query won't work right all time.

Comment: This answer just blew my mind. Are you saying that it won't delete the item if it isn't currently in view?

FYI, I did this and it worked. Thanks